# dplyr mutate with conditional values

Tags: r, dplyr

In a large dataframe ("myfile") with four columns I have to add a fifth column with values conditionally based on the first four columns.

Prefer answers with `dplyr` and `mutate`, mainly because of its speed in large datasets.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  5
2  2  4  4  1
3  1  4  1  1
4  4  5  1  3
5  5  5  5  4
...
```

The values of the fifth column (V5) are based on some conditional rules:

```
if (V1==1 & V2!=4) {
  V5 <- 1
} else if (V2==4 & V3!=1) {
  V5 <- 2
} else {
  V5 <- 0
}
```

Now I want to use the `mutate` function to use these rules on all rows (to avoid slow loops). Something like this (and yes, I know it doesn't work this way!):

```
myfile <- mutate(myfile, if (V1==1 & V2!=4){V5 = 1}
    else if (V2==4 & V3!=1){V5 = 2}
    else {V5 = 0})
```

This should be the result:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  2  3  5  1
2  2  4  4  1  2
3  1  4  1  1  0
4  4  5  1  3  0
5  5  5  5  4  0
```

How to do this in `dplyr`?

Comment: It's useful to state if V1..4 are all integer (not factor, logical, string or float)? and do you care about correctly handling `NA`, (`NaN, +Inf, -Inf`)?

Comment: If speed seems to be an issue for preferring `dplyr`, then I would better use [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try this:

```
myfile %>% mutate(V5 = (V1 == 1 & V2 != 4) + 2 * (V2 == 4 & V3 != 1))
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  2  3  5  1
2  2  4  4  1  2
3  1  4  1  1  0
4  4  5  1  3  0
5  5  5  5  4  0
```

or this:

```
myfile %>% mutate(V5 = ifelse(V1 == 1 & V2 != 4, 1, ifelse(V2 == 4 & V3 != 1, 2, 0)))
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  2  3  5  1
2  2  4  4  1  2
3  1  4  1  1  0
4  4  5  1  3  0
5  5  5  5  4  0
```

### Note

Suggest you get a better name for your data frame.  myfile makes it seem as if it holds a file name.

Above used this input:

```
myfile <- 
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L), V3 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L), V4 = c(5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

**Update 1**  Since originally posted dplyr has changed `%.%` to `%>%` so have modified answer accordingly.

**Update 2** dplyr now has `case_when` which provides another solution:

```
myfile %>% 
       mutate(V5 = case_when(V1 == 1 & V2 != 4 ~ 1, 
                             V2 == 4 & V3 != 1 ~ 2,
                             TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: I tried your second solution. I got this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, named_dots(...), environment()) : 
  REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'logical' Do you know what's going wrong?

Comment: I discovered a way which allows you to not nest the `ifelse` statements: `myfile %>% mutate(V5 = ifelse(V1 == 1 & V2 != 4, 1, 0),
                  V5 = ifelse(V2 == 4 & V3 != 1, 2, V5))`

Answer (score 46):

With `dplyr 0.7.2`, you can use the very useful `case_when` function :

```
x=read.table(
 text="V1 V2 V3 V4
 1  1  2  3  5
 2  2  4  4  1
 3  1  4  1  1
 4  4  5  1  3
 5  5  5  5  4")
x$V5 = case_when(x$V1==1 & x$V2!=4 ~ 1,
                 x$V2==4 & x$V3!=1 ~ 2,
                 TRUE ~ 0)
```

Expressed with `dplyr::mutate`, it gives:

```
x = x %>% mutate(
     V5 = case_when(
         V1==1 & V2!=4 ~ 1,
         V2==4 & V3!=1 ~ 2,
         TRUE ~ 0
     )
)
```

Please note that `NA` are not treated specially, as it can be misleading. The function will return `NA` only when no condition is matched. If you put a line with `TRUE ~ ...`, like I did in my example, the return value will then never be `NA`.

Therefore, you have to expressively tell `case_when` to put `NA` where it belongs by adding a statement like `is.na(x$V1) | is.na(x$V3) ~ NA_integer_`. Hint: the `dplyr::coalesce()` function can be really useful here sometimes!

Moreover, please note that `NA` alone will usually not work, you have to put special `NA` values : `NA_integer_`, `NA_character_` or `NA_real_`.

Comment: This was significantly faster than derivedFactor.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like `derivedFactor` from the `mosaic` package was designed for this.  In this example, it would look something like:

```
library(mosaic)
myfile <- mutate(myfile, V5 = derivedFactor(
    "1" = (V1==1 & V2!=4),
    "2" = (V2==4 & V3!=1),
    .method = "first",
    .default = 0
    ))
```

(If you want the outcome to be numeric instead of a factor, wrap the `derivedFactor` with an `as.numeric`.)

Note that the `.default` option combined with `.method = "first"` sets the "else" condition -- this approach is described in the help file for `derivedFactor`.

Comment: You can also prevent the result from being a factor using the `.asFactor = F` option or by using the (similar) `derivedVariable` function in the same package.

Comment: It looks like `recode` from dplyr 0.5 will do this.  I haven't investigated it yet though.  See https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/

Comment: This was slow for my data with 1e6 rows.

Comment: @Fato39 Yes, the `mosaic::derivedFactor` family of functions are very slow.  If you figure out why, please answer my SO question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787691/why-is-mosaicderivedfactor-twice-as-slow-as-a-base-function.  I am glad to see from your other comment that `dplyr::case_when` is faster -- I'll have to switch to that.

Comment: I'm trying the following command,library(mosaic)
VENEZ.FINAL2 <- mutate(VENEZ, SEX = derivedFactor(
  "M" = (CATEGORY== "BULL" & CATEGORY!="SIRE"),
  "F" = (CATEGORY== "COW" & CATEGORY!="HEIFER"),
  .method = "first", 
 .default = "NA")) but it doesn't work, just solve the condition
VENEZ.FINAL2 <- mutate(VENEZ, SEX = derivedFactor(
  "M" = (CATEGORY== "BULL
Could you help me? Thanks a lot!