# Mutate column into separate data frame using a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, dplyr

I would like to add new columns **into another data frame** at the end of a pipe with mutate using a condition. If the length of the variable is zero, then add a dash in the column, otherwise add the content. This is part of a loop where I bind the resulting data frames, hence all lists have only one item and the data frames here only have one row.

Is it possible with mutate to add a column into a data frame other than the one being used in the pipe?

I tried solving this using tips I found here: [Combine mutate with conditional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337394/combine-mutate-with-conditional-values)

Example code:

```
x <- "bbb"
y <- ""
end <- data.frame(a_col="aaa")

end <- x %>%
mutate (end, x_col = case_when(length()==0 ~ '-',
                         length()!=0 ~ .))

end <- y %>%
mutate (end, y_col = case_when(length()==0 ~ '-',
                         length()!=0 ~ .))
```

With both, I get this: *"Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character""*

Expected result for the 'end' data frame:

```
    a_col  x_col  y_col
1    aaa    bbb     -
```

Comment: Hey, in your `mutate` commands, you have the incorrect structure. You should use `x %>% mutate(x_col = case_when(length == 0 ~ '-', length() != 0 ~ .))`. Not to mention, this is not the way you should go. You may want to look at `if_else` from the `dplyr` packages.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible though to use mutate for adding a column to a data frame other than the one in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the behavior you were looking for?

```
x <- "bbb"
y <- ""
end <- data.frame(a_col = "aaa")

end %>% mutate(x_col = case_when(nchar(x) == 0 ~ "-",
                                 TRUE ~ x),
               y_col = case_when(nchar(y) == 0 ~ "-",
                                 TRUE ~ y))

  a_col x_col y_col
1   aaa   bbb     -
```

I think you want to use `?nchar()` instead of `?length()` so you are returned the number of characters in a string, instead of the number of elements in a vector.

The error you were getting was because you were trying to call `mutate(data = "bbb")`, but `mutate` requires the `data` argument to be a `data.frame` or at least inherit its class from `data.frame`. So it complained when you tried to pass it a `character`.

This is another way to capture multiple pipeline results in a list and them perform the empty string substitution before binding the new columns onto the existing data frame.

```
pipe_results <- list()

pipe_results[["x"]] <- x # these names become column names
pipe_results[["y"]] <- y

map_dfc(pipe_results,
        ~ gsub("^$", "-", .)) %>%
            bind_cols(end, .)
```

Comment: That is my expected output, I added it to the question together with some more explanation. Your solution works, but `x` or `y` are results of a pipeline. I wanted to add them to the separate `end` data frame with mutate at the end of their pipes. Is that possible without saving `x` and `y` and building a new pipe for adding them? Thank you

Comment: Sure it's possible. Do `x` and `y` come out of the same pipeline or are they separate products?

Comment: They are separate. Thank you!

Comment: Updated with another strategy, sorry it took me a while to get back :)