# R table-adding columns based on condition

Tags: r

The other solution marked as duplicate gave me an error when I tried it on my dataset which has categorical data as well.

I have a table with several columns. One column, column A, has 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 as values. These are codes for a certain condition. I'm trying to create/add another column, column Z, to the table which has 0 if the value in column A is 0 and 1 if the value in column A is 3 or 4. I'm trying to do it via this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(pheno_table))
    if pheno_table$columnA == 0
     then pheno_table$newcolumnZ<-0
    elsif pheno_table$columnA == 3 | pheno_table$columnA == 4
     then pheno_table$newcolumnZ<-0
```

thanks so much @see24! also, I did try this and set the working directory and such but am not able to see the file in the folder (I checked the paths)

```
    setwd('/pathtofolder/') 

    library(dplyr) df <- data.frame(A=  
    (originaltablefile$column_of_interest)) 
    newcolumn <- df %>% mutate
    (newcolumn = case_when(A == 0 ~ 0, A %in% c(3,4) ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ NA_real_)) 
    finaltablefile <- cbind(originaltablefile,newcolumn)`
```

not able to see finaltablefile in my folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine mutate with conditional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337394/combine-mutate-with-conditional-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the `mutate` and `case_when` functions from the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,0),B = c(3,4,5,6,7))
df2 <- df %>% mutate(Z = case_when(A == 0 ~ 0,
                            A %in% c(3,4) ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

I'm assuming that you want NA for rows that are not 1, 3, or 4. The `TRUE` part means if none of the above are true then... You have to use `NA_real_` because `case_when` requires all the outputs to be of the same type

Comment: Alternately, could do a left join with `mdf = data.frame(A = c(0,3,4), Z = c(0, 1, 1)); df %>% left_join(mdf)` if all comparisons are with equality.

Comment: thanks so much! im not too familiar with dplyr; could you please explain NA_real a bit more?
also could you suggest a good resource for learning dplyr? thank you!

Comment: To learn more about dplyr I suggest this excellent free online book [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html). NA is of type logical and `case_when` requires that all the outputs are the same type. So if your other outputs are numbers you need NA_real_ and if they are character you need NA_character_. See the `case_when` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/case_when) examples for more

Comment: thanks so much @see24! also, I did try this and set the working directory and such but am not able to see the file in the folder (I checked the paths)

   ` setwd('/pathtofolder/')

     library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = (originaltablefile$column_of_interest))
newcolumn <- df %>% mutate(newcolumn = case_when(A == 0 ~ 0,
                                   A %in% c(3,4) ~ 1,
                                   TRUE ~ NA_real_))

finaltablefile <- cbind(originaltablefile,newcolumn)`

not able to see finaltablefile in my folder.

Comment: You have created finaltablefile in the R environment if you want to save it to a folder you need to do that explicitly. You can use `write.csv` to save it as a csv file or you could use `save(finaltablefile, file = "finaltablefile.RData")` to save it as an R object that you can load in the future with `load()`. If you type `ls()` you will see the objects that you have created in the R environment. I recommend getting RStudio as it makes keeping track of the objects in the environment much easier

Comment: @analog_kid if this answer worked for you it would be much appreciated if you accepted it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.