# R - Creating a new variable using same condition on many variables

Tags: r

I am quite a beginner in R and I am stuck with this problem:

I have a dataset (data) of 24 columns. Each column is an answer to a question : "Is your xxx hurting"? xxx varies in each column (it can be back, head...)
Each column can take 3 values: 1 if it does not hurt, 2 if it hurts a bit, 3 if it pains.

I want to create a new variable (fragile) to count each time a person said it hurted a bit somewhere.

```
data$fragile <- ifelse(data$var1 ==2 , 1, 0) + ifelse(data$var2 == 2, 1, 0) + ...
```

But it is quite long so I would like to not do it

I tried doing a loop but I read somewhere that R is not made to do loops (and my loop does not work anyway)

```
data$fragile <-  for(i in dataset[1:24]){ifelse(i == 2, 1, 0)}
```

And when I do `head(data$fragile)`, "NULL" appears...

What should I do?

I am sure this question has already been asked several times but I do not find the right keywords.

Comment: This could be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337394/dplyr-mutate-with-conditional-values 

In `R` when you want to create a new variable you can use the function  `mutate`  from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the assumption that you columns of interest have the indices `1:24`:

```
data$fragile <- apply( data[1:24], 1, function(x) sum(x==2, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

If you have the columns in a different order just change the index.

This solution, however, is quite slow compared to `rowSums`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I saw that many rows of my new variable fragile were removed into missing values because I assume that in at least one of the other variables, they did not answer the question. How can I resolve this matter?

Comment: Both `sum`and `rowSums` support an argument `na.rm`. If you set this to `TRUE`the functions will ignore any missing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
data$fragile <- +(rowSums(data == 2) > 0)
```

This will give 1 to `fragile` column if there is 2 in any of the column for a particular row.

---

In the new `dplyr` 1.0.0 we can use `rowwise` with `cur_data()`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(fragile = +(any(cur_data() == 2)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!