# Making a function ignore the first row in R

Tags: r

So I have this table about virus and it's infections/death/etc. Here is my code and original table:

```
data <- clean_names(read.csv("Book1.csv"))
TableN <- data %>% mutate(PeopleInfected = Suseptible* 1/8) %>% mutate(PeopleDeadFromInfection = PeopleInfected * 1/8) %>%
mutate(ImmuneFromSmallpox = PeopleInfected - PeopleDeadFromInfection) 

        > head(TableN)
      age Susceptible PeopleInfected PeopleDeadFromInfection ImmuneFromSmallpox
    1   0      1300        162.500                20.31250          142.18750
    2   1      1000        125.000                15.62500          109.37500
    3   2       855        106.875                13.35938           93.51562
    4   3       798         99.750                12.46875           87.28125
    5   4       760         95.000                11.87500           83.12500
    6   5       732         91.500                11.43750           80.06250
```

There is a 1/8 chance of getting the virus, and an additional 1/8 chance of dying from it. Those who survive are forever immune to the virus. As a result, I have to subtract the 'ImmuneFromSmallpox' column from 'suspectible' to account for those who survived and are forever immune from the virus.

Here is what the table should look like:

```
> head(TableN)
  age Susceptible PeopleInfected PeopleDeadFromInfection ImmuneFromSmallpox
1   0      1300        162.500                20.31250          142.18750
2   1      858.8125    107.226                13.40335          93.82265
3   2      761.17735   95.1471                11.89339          83.25371
```

To be more clear, I want the first row to stay the same, but I want the other rows to change. What function do you recommend I use?

Comment: Why do values in `PeopleInfected`, `PeopleDeadFromInfection` and `ImmuneFromSmallpox` change in your desired output?

Comment: I am accounting for the people who already had the virus. They are forever immune to it now. Here are the calculations as follows. Keep in mind, the infection rate of it is 1/8, and the death rate of it is 1/8. For people aged 0 (newborn), 1300 * 1/8 = 162.5 get infected and 20.3 die. The 142.2 newborn who survive can no longer get the virus, therefore, we subtract 142.2 people off of the susceptible column. Keep in mind it was originally 1000 for age 1, so we get 858.8125. For children aged 1, 1/8 get infected and 1/8 die. The calculation repeats for each age. Hope that explained it well!

Comment: @codermcgee There are quite a few answers now that show you many different ways of achieving the result. Please accept whichever answer you think is most helpful by clicking on the v-sign next to the beginning of each answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `replace` over the first `ImmuneFromSmallpox` value, e.g.,

```
transform(
  df,
  survivors = survivors - replace(ImmuneFromSmallpox, 1, 0)
)
```

or logical value `seq(nrow(df)) > 1`

```
transform(
  df,
  survivors = survivors - ImmuneFromSmallpox * (seq(nrow(df)) > 1)
)
```

which gives

```
  age survivors PeopleInfected PeopleDeadFromInfection ImmuneFromSmallpox
1   0 1300.0000        162.500                20.31250          142.18750
2   1  890.6250        125.000                15.62500          109.37500
3   2  761.4844        106.875                13.35938           93.51562
4   3  710.7188         99.750                12.46875           87.28125
5   4  676.8750         95.000                11.87500           83.12500
6   5  651.9375         91.500                11.43750           80.06250
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(age = 0:5, survivors = c(1300L, 1000L, 855L, 798L, 
760L, 732L), PeopleInfected = c(162.5, 125, 106.875, 99.75, 95,
91.5), PeopleDeadFromInfection = c(20.3125, 15.625, 13.35938,
12.46875, 11.875, 11.4375), ImmuneFromSmallpox = c(142.1875,
109.375, 93.51562, 87.28125, 83.125, 80.0625)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",        
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try subsetting:

```
data <- clean_names(read.csv("Book1.csv"))

data[-1,] <- data[-1,] %>% mutate(...)
```

Here, subsetting the data.frame on both sides with `df[-1,]` means that you are only operating on all rows but the first one. After you have done this, you can call `data` to see that all but the first row have changed.

More generally, you can create vectors with row numbers to pick just the rows you want to work on. Say, `idx = c(1,3,5)`. Then, `data[idx,]` would pick up rows 1, 3 and 5 from `data`. The minus in `data[-1,]` is an R-shorthand for excluding the first row. Similarly, if you wanted to pick up specific columns, you can do the same using `data[, col_idx]`. If your data.frame has explicit rownames, then you can also call those like you would call columns.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use case_when, as in this answer. [dplyr mutate with conditional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337394/dplyr-mutate-with-conditional-values).

But to be honest, I'd just be hacky about it and break off the top row, then mutate the rest, then rbind them back together. Getting all rows except the first can be done with `data[2:nrow(data),]`.

Answer (score 0):

Tryt he following :

```
library(dplyr)

TableN %>% 
  mutate(Susceptible = Susceptible - lag(ImmuneFromSmallpox, default = 0),
         PeopleInfected = Susceptible* 1/8, 
         PeopleDeadFromInfection = PeopleInfected * 1/8) -> TableN

TableN
```